# How to modify k8s node annotation with rest patch operation

Tags: kubernetes

I want to update the annotation nodescore of the node.
I can do it successfully with cli command as below:

```
kubectl patch node <node-name> -p '{"metadata":{"annotations":{"nodescore":"1.

00"}}}'

But when I tried to do it with rest api like below:

    retval = self.api_core_v1.patch_node(nodename, {'metadata': {'annotations':
```

{'nodescore': '0.50'}}})
I got response like this:

```
*** Not yet returned!
```

I'm using kubernetes 26.1.0
I'm following the api in doc: https://k8s-python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kubernetes.client.apis.html#module-kubernetes.client.apis.core_v1_api

patch_node(name, body, **kwargs)

```
partially update the specified Node This method makes a synchronous HTTP request by default. To make an asynchronous HTTP request, please pass async_req=True >>> thread = api.patch_node(name, body, async_req=True) >>> result = thread.get()

:param async_req bool :param str name: name of the Node (required) :param object body: (required) :param str pretty: If ‘true’, then the output is pretty printed. :param str dry_run: When present, indicates that modifications should not be persisted. An invalid or unrecognized dryRun directive will result in an error response and no further processing of the request. Valid values are: - All: all dry run stages will be processed :return: V1Node

    If the method is called asynchronously, returns the request thread.
```

Comment: Are you following any doc? If yes can you add it to your question. How did you get the Rest API?

Comment: added the Rest API docs that I followed